# Load new form from button and from timer are handled differently

Tags: vb.net

When i login into my application and i get to the menu form, after the form triggers the form.shown after 1 second timer i start an update procedure.
This procedure calls another form which is on top the menu form, and does certain things.
This update form can also be called from a button that is on the menu form.
The problem here is when i call this form from the button the taskbar is hidden and also the menu form which is at the back is unclickable(I set my application to be full screen so taskbar is not visible). When the update form opens from the timer the taskbar appears, and the menu form which is at the back is clickable, and the user can click buttons from the parent form. 
I tried setting focus on the update form after is loaded from the processes of windows but it didn't change anything.
I dont want to show the taskbar nor have clickable parent form.

Any idea why is this happening and how can i fix it?

Here is how i call my form from timer and from the button:

```
Private Sub TimerDelayedStart_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    TimerDelayedStart.Stop()
    LoadUpdateDatabase()
End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    LoadUpdateDatabase()
End Sub

    Private Sub LoadUpdateDatabase()
        Try
            fUpdateDatabase = New frmUpdateDatabase
            With fUpdateDatabase
                .ShowDialog()
                Cursor = Cursors.Default
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: There are a few things you can try. -Calling Me.BringToFront(). -Using Me.BeginInvoke in your timer method. -Setting the owner of your form to the parent and disabling the menu while the form is open.

Comment: There is a form event called `Shown` that you could use instead of the timer. `Shown` fires after the original form has finished drawing.

Comment: This is the 1st thing i tried @SSS. I called the update in the frmMeny.shown.
But the screen is stuck in an intermediate state when the update is called. 
it seems that the update needs to be called after the shown is completed. Thats why i used timer, and i also tried background worker.
And also tried setting a small delay in the shown trigger and then execute update but nothing changed.

Comment: By the way @apc I fixed the taskbar issue. I remove the property show in taskbar and now its ok. Only thing left now is to make parent unclickable.

Comment: @apc the invoke worked. Thanks m. Write it as an answer so i can mark it if you want